# How do I build a docker image from a Sveltekit app

Tags: docker, sveltekit

I am trying to build a docker image from a sample app I have created in Sveltekit.

I am using the @sveltejs/adapter-auto and have included both .js files for API calls and .svelte files in my routes folder.

Here is my Dockerfile (which builds fine, but might not be correct)

```
FROM node:14.15.0 as build

# install dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci

# Copy all local files into the image.
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

###
# Only copy over the Node pieces we need
# ~> Saves 35MB
###
FROM node:14.15.0

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/.svelte-kit/build/. .


EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "./app.js"]
```

When I try to run a container from the docker image, I get the error output

```
(node:1) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/app/app.js:1
import { respond } from '@sveltejs/kit/ssr';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

My package.json does contain `"type": "module"`

```
{
  "name": "backendtest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "svelte-kit dev",
    "build": "svelte-kit build",
    "package": "svelte-kit package",
    "preview": "svelte-kit preview",
    "lint": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --check --plugin-search-dir=. .",
    "format": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --write --plugin-search-dir=. ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "next",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.4.0",
    "svelte": "^3.44.0"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

When I try to run `npm run build` in my local build environment I get the message.

```
Using @sveltejs/adapter-auto
  Could not detect a supported production environment. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#adapters to learn how to configure your app to run on the platform of your choosing
```

As I am new to svelte, not sure if this is correct.

If I try to use the node adapter, I get an error

```
config.kit.adapter should be an object with an "adapt" method. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#adapters
Error: config.kit.adapter should be an object with an "adapt" method. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#adapters
    at file:///Users/simon/development/svelte/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/cli.js:391:12
    at file:///Users/simon/development/svelte/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/cli.js:599:43
    at file:///Users/simon/development/svelte/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/cli.js:585:18
    at file:///Users/simon/development/svelte/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/cli.js:585:18
    at validate_config (file:///Users/simon/development/svelte/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/cli.js:739:9)
    at load_config (file:///Users/simon/development/svelte/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/cli.js:704:20)
    at async get_config (file:///Users/simon/development/svelte/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/cli.js:774:10)
    at async file:///Users/simon/development/svelte/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/cli.js:884:18
```

Here is my svelte.config.js contents

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),

        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        target: '#svelte'
    }
};

export default config;
```

I have also tried the following svelte.config.js as per the github docs, but get the same "adapt" error

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      // default options are shown
      out: 'build',
      precompress: false,
      env: {
        host: 'HOST',
        port: 'PORT',
      },
    }),
  },
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should include your `package.json` in your final Docker image.

**Edit:** Also I'm not sure you should use .svelte-kit/build since this is an intermediate result used by sveltekit internally. You should have a build folder after running build task but I'm not sure cause I never used auto adapter, I usually use node adapter.

Mine basically looks like this:

```
COPY --from=build /app/package.json /app/build /.
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Comment: Looking closer at the build process when run in my dev environment, after running npm run build, I get the following message.

Using @sveltejs/adapter-auto
  Could not detect a supported production environment. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#adapters to learn how to configure your app to run on the platform of your choosing

Comment: I am also getting errors if I try to use the node adapter. I have updated my question with my findings.

Comment: What did you set your adapter to when changing to node, share the config please?

Comment: I have updated my question with code from svelte.config.js at the bottom.

Comment: Did you install next version of adapter node? `npm i -D @sveltejs/adapter-node@next`

Comment: It works, that was it. I had just install adapter-node not @next. Thanks so much, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @PrestonDocks would you be willing to post to full working Dockerfile?

Comment: @AdamTegen Sorry, I don't have it anymore. I was loving svelte and SvelteKit, but when I started to try and do more with it, I came unstuck. The deal-breaker was the Svelte API not supporting file uploads. Then I thought what else might I be missing here. Also, I didn't see the point of having a Svelte API and a separate API just for the things that I can't do with Svelte. Not directly what you were asking about, but relevant I think, as it's the reason I don't have the Dockerfile to share with you.

Comment: @AdamTegen If you're still looking for a full working Docerfile for SvelteKit apps, check out https://gist.github.com/AradAlvand/04b2cad14b00e5ffe8ec96a3afbb34fb

Comment: This YouTube video gives step by step instructions to setup a SvelteKit project to run in docker https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVMG2nWjWk4